# Restrict user to type less than 5 characters in DevExpress's TextEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to restrict user to type less than 5 characters. I googled and solution was to set `maxLength` for `textbox`, but I'm using `DevExpress`'s `TextEdit` and it doesn't have `maxLength`. So how can I do this?

**EDIT**

`DevExpress`'s `TextEdit`  has `maxLength` in branch of properties in properties in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looked in Devexpress documentation and it has a control that does that. I dont know if you are using WPF or Windows Forms or you are building a website, though its the same thing. DevExpress Documentation is more than good,it has everything you need to know with a simple search.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6945/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Editors/Common-Features/Masked-Input

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TextEdit.Properties.MaxLength property to 5.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit.MaxLength.property